# Docker image creation using nodejs with redis

Tags: dockerfile

i am using below Docker file. how can i configure redis in my Dockerfile?

also i am using build command `docker build - < Dockerfile` but this didn't work out.
if i run this command the following error will show

> COPY failed: no source files were specified

```
FROM node:lts

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app

RUN yarn

COPY . /app

CMD ["yarn","run","start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot use `docker build - < Dockerfile` to build an image that uses `COPY` instructions, because those instructions require those files to be present in the build context.

One must use `docker build .`, where `.` is the relative path to the build context.

Using `docker build - < Dockerfile` effectively means that the only thing in the build context is the Dockerfile. The files that one wants to copy into the docker image are not known to docker, because they are not included in the context.